# Abstracting duplicate controller logic into service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two controllers, and a directive. Both controllers have the same type of data, an array of filters. Both controllers use the same functions to manipulate this data, but the functions are dependent on `this` (the scope with "controller as" syntax). How can I abstract these functions into a service but have the data live in the controller? I thought of passing the scope around, but as I read this is bad practice. Any ideas?

```
.controller('CtrlOne', function() {
  this.filters = [...]; // this data is unique for controller one

  // Want to abstract these into a service
  this.isAllSelected = true;

  this.handleChangeFilter = function(selected) {
    ...
  }.bind(this);

  this.handleShowFilter = function(filter) {
    ...
  }.bind(this);
})

.controller('CtrlTwo', function() {
  this.filters = [...]; // this data is unique for controller two

  // Want to abstract this into a service
  // it is the exact same logic as the other service
  // only thing that changes is `this.filters`
  this.isAllSelected = true;

  this.handleChangeFilter = function(selected) {
    ...
  }.bind(this);

  this.handleShowFilter = function(filter) {
    ...
  }.bind(this);
})

.directive('filtering', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'filtering.html',
    scope: {},
    bindToController: {
      filters: '=',
      onChangeFilter: '=',
      onShowFilter: '='
    },
    controllerAs: 'filtering',
    controller: function() {
    }
  }
})

// filtering.html
`
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="filter in filtering.filters"
      ng-click="filtering.onChangeFilter(filter)"
      ng-show="filtering.onShowFilter(filter)">
    <span ng-style="{color: filter.isActive ? 'red' : 'inherit'}">
      {{filter.name}}
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
`

// Using the filtering directive
`
<filtering
  on-change-filter="::ctrlOne.handleChangeFilter"
  on-show-filter="::ctrlOne.handleShowFilter"
  filters="::ctrlOne.filters">
</filtering>
`
```

Comment: I´m not sure if there is a better approach, but I usually use this one: http://blog.revolunet.com/blog/2014/02/14/angularjs-services-inheritance/

Comment: you should be able to just move your functions into a service and then injeect the service into each controller. and then when you call the service function in each controller  use call, apply or bind to make sure that this refers to what you need it too

Comment: @juvian: Yes, I saw that somewhere else as well, I didn't know if this is good practice as services are supposed to be singletons, but it seems this is the only way so far, unless I'm missing something...

Comment: @TimCodes: I thought of that too, but that would qualify as passing the scope around, there would be no difference in doing `f(scope, param)` than `f.call(this, param)`, and I read this is not good practice.

Comment: I thik If your using this your not binding to $scope your binding to your controller. The problems that come with $scope shadowing and inheritance. hopefully shouldnt be an issue

Comment: could you move your two filters array into the service as well ?

Comment: use named objects in functions instead of relying on exectuion context with this?

Comment: You can create a singleton service that returns a base controller function with methods defined in function prototype. Then you can inherit your controller function from the service by using `myController.prototype = Object.create(myService.prototype);` and then in your controller function just issue a call to base controller service constructor: `myService.call(this);`

Comment: @ConstantinePoltyrev, I'd appreciate if you could post an answer with your proposed solution to see the big picture.

Comment: @TimCodes: could you post your solution as well?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following, but I'm open to other solutions as I'm not sure this is idiomatic Angular:

```
.controller('CtrlOne', function(filterHandler) {
  this.filters = [...]; // this data is unique for controller one
  this.filterHandler = filterHandler.create(this.filters);
})

.controller('CtrlTwo', function(filterHandler) {
  this.filters = [...]; // this data is unique for controller two
  this.filterHandler = filterHandler.create(this.filters);
})

.directive('filtering', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'filtering.html',
    scope: {},
    bindToController: {
      filters: '=',
      onChangeFilter: '=',
      onShowFilter: '='
    },
    controllerAs: 'filtering',
    controller: function() {
    }
  }
})

.service('filterHandler', function() {
  return {
    create: function() {
      var isAllSelected = true;
      return {
        change: function(selected) {
          ...
        },
        show: function(filter) {
          ...
        }
      };
    }
  }
})

// filtering.html
`
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="filter in filtering.filters"
      ng-click="filtering.onChangeFilter(filter)"
      ng-show="filtering.onShowFilter(filter)">
    <span ng-style="{color: filter.isActive ? 'red' : 'inherit'}">
      {{filter.name}}
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
`

// Using the filtering directive
`
<filtering
  on-change-filter="::ctrlOne.filterHandler.change"
  on-show-filter="::ctrlOne.filterHandler.show"
  filters="::ctrlOne.filters">
</filtering>
`
```

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong in my comment about using a service. With a service there arises a chiken-egg problem when you need to inject the service before you create the controller.
So I just wrote a globally available base controller function-class and here is a fully working runnable example which I believe is self-explanatory:

```js
function BaseController() {
  this.message = "Base controller message";
  this.init();
  
  // Common constructor code
}

BaseController.prototype = {
  someFunction: function() {
    // This is to show the output (alert does not work in sandbox) 
    this.output = this.message; 
    // Uncomment this to see an alert
    // alert(this.message); 
  }
  ,init: function(){
    throw('Cannot use abstract base class');
  }
};


angular.module('myModule', [])
  .controller('myFirstController', myFirstController)
  .controller('mySecondController', mySecondController);



function myFirstController() {
  BaseController.call(this);
}

myFirstController.prototype = Object.create(BaseController.prototype);

myFirstController.prototype.init = function() {
  this.message = 'First Controller Message';
}


function mySecondController() {
  BaseController.call(this);
  
}

mySecondController.prototype = Object.create(BaseController.prototype);

mySecondController.prototype.init = function() {
  this.message = 'Second Controller Message';
}
```

```html
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="myFirstController as ctl">
      <button ng-click="ctl.someFunction()">Call method from first controller</button>
      <div>
      Output: {{ctl.output}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="mySecondController as ctl">
      <button ng-click="ctl.someFunction()">Call method from second controller</button>
      <div>
      Output: {{ctl.output}}
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </body>
```